# Group List of hashes and index the values

Tags: ruby, hash

I has an array of hashes

Some hashes are duplicate

I want to keep the duplicate, but add counter to the title

For example "TITLE #1" And "TITLE #2"

This is my Array

```
list = []
@temp = {}
@temp["name"] = "Germany"
@temp["id"] = 1
list << @temp

@temp["name"] = "USA"
@temp["id"] = 2
list << @temp

@temp["name"] = "USA"
 @temp["id"] = 3
list << @temp

@temp["name"] = "France" 
@temp["id"] = 4
list << @temp

@temp["name"] = "France" 
@temp["id"] = 5
list << @temp

@temp["name"] = "France" 
@temp["id"] = 6
list << @temp
```

I Want the result Same as the source but near "USA" add the counter "USA #1" and "USA #2"
And France change to "France #1", "France #2" "France #3"

No change on germany element because there are not multiple items

Comment: The example you provided contains an error. By updating `@temp` instead of reinstantiating a new hash for each new record, you are adding items to your list that all reference the same hash in memory. This results in your list looking like it contains 6 items for `{ "name" => "France", "id" => 6 }`

Comment: This question concerns the manipulation of the array `list`, not how `list` was constructed. I therefore suggest you replace your code with `list` after the calculations have been performed, as shown in my answer. Generally, when you give an example, assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `list = [...]`). That way, readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them. Also, show your desired result, which here is the array shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need `@temp = 0` at the beginning of each block of code.

After executing your code with the modification

```
list = [{"name"=>"Germany", "id"=>1},
        {"name"=>"USA", "id"=>2},
        {"name"=>"USA", "id"=>3},
        {"name"=>"France", "id"=>4},
        {"name"=>"France", "id"=>5},
        {"name"=>"France", "id"=>6}]
```

We can then obtain your desired result as follows.

```
list.group_by { |h| h["name"] }.values.flat_map do |a|
  a.map.with_index(1) do |h,i|
    base = h["name"]
    h.merge("name"=>base +" #{i}")
  end
end
  #=> [{"name"=>"Germany 1", "id"=>1},
  #    {"name"=>"USA 1", "id"=>2},
  #    {"name"=>"USA 2", "id"=>3},
  #    {"name"=>"France 1", "id"=>4},
  #    {"name"=>"France 2", "id"=>5},
  #    {"name"=>"France 3", "id"=>6}]
```

Note

```
arr = list.group_by { |h| h["name"] }.values
  #=> [[{"name"=>"Germany", "id"=>1}],
  #    [{"name"=>"USA", "id"=>2}, {"name"=>"USA", "id"=>3}],
  #    [{"name"=>"France", "id"=>4}, {"name"=>"France", "id"=>5},
  #     {"name"=>"France", "id"=>6}]]
```

Had I used [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) rather than [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map), the result would have been

```
  [[{"name"=>"Germany 1", "id"=>1}],
   [{"name"=>"USA 1", "id"=>2}, {"name"=>"USA 2", "id"=>3}],
   [{"name"=>"France 1", "id"=>4}, {"name"=>"France 2", "id"=>5},
    {"name"=>"France 3", "id"=>6}]]
```

Using `flat_map` is equivalent to inserting a splat in front of each of this array's elements.

```
  [*[{"name"=>"Germany 1", "id"=>1}],
   *[{"name"=>"USA 1", "id"=>2}, {"name"=>"USA 2", "id"=>3}],
   *[{"name"=>"France 1", "id"=>4}, {"name"=>"France 2", "id"=>5},
    {"name"=>"France 3", "id"=>6}]]
```